# Why $C(X,Y)$ ,namely the morphisms between $X$ and $Y$, is assumed to be a set rather than a class?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

I understand that we introduce the notion of class to bypass the paradox of the "set of all sets". However, shouldn't $C(X,Y)$ considered to be the set of all morphisms between $X$ and $Y$, thus not a set? My interpretation is that it is contained in the $Mor(C)$($C$ a category), so it has to be a set, rather a class. But how exactly should we recognize an object as a class? It is somehow difficult in more general cases to know whether an object is contained in something else or not.

Comment: Related question on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48810/why-need-the-morphisms-to-form-a-set

Comment: Is there more elementary interpretations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a category $C$, and two objects $X,Y$ in $C$, the *hom-set* (for homomorphism set) is given by
$$C(X,Y) = \{f \mid f \text{ is an arrow } f: X \rightarrow Y \text{ in } C\}.$$
Now, despite the name, there is no a priori reason why this should be a set, rather than a class. Indeed, it is not difficult to give an example where a hom-set is a proper class, but a bit more difficult to give an example that doesn't feel artifical. Categories where all hom-sets *are* sets are called *locally small*, and the reason why some authors restrict themselves to only considering locally small categories is (presumably) because the Yoneda Lemma, one of the most important results in category theory, only holds for locally small categories.

One example of a category which is not locally small is the category of locally small categories. Let $C$ be a category which is locally small but not small (i.e. has a proper class of objects), and let $1$ be the terminal category. Then any functor $1 \rightarrow C$ corresponds to an object of $C$, and hence the collection of functors must be a proper class as well.

Note also that this entire discussion depends very much on your chosen foundations. As @Stefan points out, allowing non-locally small categories can lead you into trouble in some foundations, and in other foundations, it does not even make sense to make this distinction.

Comment: Isn't it because it is contained in $Mor(C)$, then it can only be a set?

Comment: @Keith The collection of morphisms in $C$ could be a proper class.

Comment: I am confused. Isn't set $A$ defined to be the class contained in another class $C$, whether $C$ is proper or not.

Comment: @Keith You are right. Given a sufficiently rich axiomatization of set theory, we cannot allow classes to contain proper classes (, because Russel's paradoxon would carry over). One could introduce 2nd order classes which are allowed to contain proper classes and 3rd order classes which are allowed to contain proper 2nd order classes and so on... But this is quite messy and up to this point, the trouble seems to outweigh the benefit for most people. And yes, this is one reason why we ask for a set of morphisms, rather than a proper class.

Comment: @ mrp can you explain why the hom set is a proper class in the category of all categories？

Comment: @Keith I updated my answer a bit.